# Combining two sets of principal components in a regression

Tags: regression, pca, predictive-models

My data set consists of a large number of time series of two frequencies: daily and monthly. I am interested in doing a predictive regression on a monthly and weekly basis.

I am thinking of dividing my data set in two (daily and monthly), and then do principal component analysis on each subset individually and use the two separate sets of principal components in my predictive regression.

Are there any contraindications in combining two separate sets of principal components (one from the daily and one from the monthly data) in a regression?

Comment: Your proposal does not appear to address the principal difficulty, which concerns the changes of support: finding a reasonable way to compare the daily values to the monthly values and to predict weekly values from monthly values.

Comment: The changes of support is still a concern, but a proposal is to do daily interpolation from the monthly (and weekly) data. Possible interpolation schemes include 'last observation carried forward' or linear interpolation.